# How to call a method of a custom datagridview control?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a custom control that I'm also using as a DataGridView control. This custom control has a method called `SetHttpClient`and I pass a HttpClient object as parameter.

How can I call this method from the parent form? (The parent form only knows about the instance of the class deriving from DataGridViewTextBoxCell)

Answer (score 0):

You should build a nice structure for this. For example if you have two Forms, and in Form 1 you have the Grid, which you want to refresh From Form 2. If you want to open Form 2, you should pass the instance of the Grid from on creating the instance.

Or a second way, Form 2 provide an event which will be subscribed in Form 1. And the event is called if the Grid should be refreshed. You can than pass the HttpClient over the Args-Object to Form 1.

Please tell me, if i misunderstand you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use a ViewModels to communicate with View instead of one View execute action on second View.

So, for example your View like

**CustomersView** contains **CustomersViewModel** in DataContext, if you execute a operation **GetData** you make it in **CustomersViewModel** and the result put to **DataGridView**.

This solution moves responsibility of providing data from class **DataGridView** to **CustomersViewModel**. The ViewModel can use some Service or other mechanism to provide you data using **HttpClient**.

I know that's not straight answer for your question, but is good solution for your problem.

In this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx you have method **GetParts**, you can imagine that the body of this method contains HttpClient and get the data from a website.

Answer (score 0):

May be you're talking about access modifiers like private, public, internal.

If so, then in child form make access modifier like public or internal.
And in parent form just make needed call.

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal String HellowWorld_mt(string SuffixValue)
    {
        return "hello world and "+ SuffixValue;
    }
}


public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm cf = new ChildForm();
        cf.Show();
        string resp = cf.HellowWorld_mt(" extra!");
        this.Text = resp;
    }
}
```

[More about that: Access Modifiers (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)